# How can i build iconv as static library?

Tags: xcode, makefile, iconv, libiconv

i want build iconv as static library on my MacOSX
i downloaded sources from http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/ and tried:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

This process only makes `libiconv.dylib`, a dynamic library.

How can I build the static library `libiconv.a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run configure as follows:

```
./configure --enable-static
```

Then run `make` and you will see the static library `./lib/.libs/libiconv.a`

To find this option, run `./configure --help`:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep static
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=no]
```

Comment: Yes.  My previous answer `--with-static` was incorrect, so I deleted it.  I just tried @Nirk's answer and it works, so I think this should become the accepted answer.